# Is there a canonical map of Babylon 5?

Tags: babylon-5, map

Throughout the TV series *Babylon 5*, we hear about different sections of the eponymous space station referred to by colours and numbers, e.g. "Green Two" or "Grey Seventeen". These two parts of the classification system seem to be orthogonal: e.g. in the episode "Ceremonies of Light and Dark" in S3, a call is traced to the Green sector and also found to be from level 14, after which they know it comes from Green Fourteen.

I love a good bit of worldbuilding, *especially* detailed maps of imaginary places. Is it ever explained, perhaps in supplementary materials to the show, exactly how the different "sectors" and "levels" are organised? Is there a canonical map of Babylon 5 showing all the coloured and numbered regions?

Comment: Please don't mention Grey 17.

Comment: @IanThompson - It's missing, and I'm ok with that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Babylon 5's Art Director Ted Haigh was kind enough to provide a map in the [Feb 1993 edition of Cinefantastique](https://www.charmgear.top/magazine-back-issues-c-1_3/cinefantastiquwbre-magazine-feb-1993-babylon-5-ren-and-stimpy-tmnt-p-196.html). This shows each of the major sections and their functions.

[image]

From the show itself (and the in-universe map seen in B5: Shadow Dancing) we can extrapolate the various sectors, their locations and function;

- [Brown](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Brown_Sector) - Life Support and Waste Reclamation facilities
- [Blue](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Blue_Sector) - Maintenance and Operational controls
- [Green](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Sector) - Arponics and the ambassadorial quarters.
- [Grey](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Grey_Sector) - Atmosphere monitoring and the station's original power station.
- [Red](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Sector) - Public and Commercial facilities including hotels and Medlab
- [Yellow](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Yellow_Sector) - Power supply, fuel tanks, various labs.

[image]

This non-canon (but otherwise excellent) image from the licensed [B5 Station Guide RPG](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/59845/babylon-5-station-guide), courtesy of [TheWertZone](http://thewertzone.blogspot.co.uk/2017/06/babylon-5-rewatch-setting-scene-babylon.html) seems a solid reference.

[image]

---

As an aside, based on Mr Garibaldi's trips in the elevator in [B5: Grey 17 is Missing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_17_Is_Missing), we can reasonably assume that levels don't simply go from top to bottom (like decks on a Trek starship) but circulate *outward from the core of the station in concentric rings* with level 1 at the innermost and level 20+ at the outside.

Comment: So B5 is basically a metal greenhouse with bits tacked on each end? Ummm...

Comment: @JonClements - That's the very point and essence of an [O'Neill Cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Neill_cylinder)

Comment: If you compare the wertzone image with the one in the answer below for the station guide, they are the same.

Comment: @JohnP - You are, of course correct.

Comment: I never realised there was a reason to call it the "brown" sector...

Comment: "we can reasonably assume that levels don't simply go from top to bottom" I don't think it ever occurred to me that anyone could think otherwise. In a rotating cylinder, outside is down. How would any other system work?

Comment: @Acccumulation - Well, the station has an (orientation) top to bottom.

Comment: " Well, the station has an (orientation) top to bottom." Can you elaborate/provide cites? Do you mean there is some Euclidean coordinates that are used to describe the station? AFAIK, whenever they talk about "down below", they mean the outside.

Comment: @Acccumulation - When they refer to "downbelow", they mean Brown Sector. At the bottom of the station. Literally (and also figuratively) down, below them.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, even though I was hoping for more detailed info, because it's the best I've got. Be warned that I may move the tick if something better comes along later :-)

Answer (score 12):

[The Babylon 5 Station Guide](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/59845/babylon-5-station-guide) (now out of print) contains more maps than you can shake a stick at. It has several books containing lots of maps, including pages and pages of deck plans, along with four double-sided posters containing more maps.

[image: Photo of the product]

I'm not sure how canonical it is. It was an officially licensed product. I *think* JMS had to give approval for the final version of each of Mongoose's products.

Comment: This link includes some commentary from JMS on the Mongoose books and their 'canon' status http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/The_Babylon_Project_talk:Canon